# Delay For Loop for a specific amount of time - Android

Tags: android, loops, delay, sleep, keystroke

I am trying to simulate a keystroke by setting setPressed to true and then via a postDelay setting setPressed to false a few ticks later.  My issue is this works perfectly when applied once but when I try to iterate through a list with multiple elements the delays I believe run over one another.  The iterations are much too fast.  I believe the solution would be to delay the loop from iterating for a period of time just longer than the postDelayed, but I am not having much success with this either.

```
public void myOnClickListener(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.test:
        //adds two random digits to list
        addRandomDigits(2);

        int size = list.size();
        System.out.println("Size: " + size);
            tmpButton = map.get(list.get(list.size()-1));
            tmpButton.setPressed(true);
            tmpButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tmpButton.setPressed(false);
                }
            }, 200);

        Log.e("**droid", "Droid sequence: " + getArrayListAsString(list));
        break;
```

If this solution does not seem to be the most efficient, logical, etc., I am wide open to any suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loop, i would like to suggest you to use TimerTask Class for the execution at a particular time period.

```
private class myLoop extends TimerTask
{
       public void run()
       {
           // Place your code here.

           addRandomDigits(2);

           int size = list.size();
           System.out.println("Size: " + size);
           tmpButton = map.get(list.get(list.size()-1));
           tmpButton.setPressed(true);
           tmpButton.setPressed(false);

          Log.e("**droid", "Droid sequence: " + getArrayListAsString(list));
          break;
       }
}
```

you need to make your tmpButton as static.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response.  How am I to iterate through the list without a loop?  For example, if in the list were {1,2,3,4,5} I would like the setPressed(true) then setPressed(false) for button #1, then button#2, and so on to simulate keystrokes.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Arjun, am I using TimerTask's schedule(...) somewhere within your suggestion.  Just having trouble piecing this together.  I've been at this solution for 4 days and almost looking for a gimme.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: added additional code to original post... if you need more (there isn't much more to it) let me know and I'll gladly supply.  thanks in advance

Comment: how is this class used in the onClickListener which the code was previously in?

Comment: ok look at this example of TimerTask http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm

Comment: I've tried implementing the TimerTask into the solution.  It makes much more sense to me but I am getting a "called from wrong thread" exception.  I believe it has to do with postDelay being called while on the TimerTask thread.  I'll keep messing around with this and will post my solution.